# how to display web api result to a dropdown list control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I got response from a Web API.The API is returning a list of objects in JSON format.but couldn't display results to dropdownlist control.

you can see my codes in these pictures.Please help me?

Comment: the links of images are : https://ibb.co/WfjkDdS     https://ibb.co/PwDTbhM

Comment: Create a model for the JSON so you can bind the result easily. If possible can you please provide the JSON result in the question?

Comment: @Golda, Thanks for your answer. https://ibb.co/jydDyQ6 you can see the result. I created model but couldn't display result to the control.

Comment: @EmreOztoprak why not you pasted your code here ?

Comment: sorry @vishuminhas, 
I'm new to this site. didn't know how to do it.

Comment: @Golda, thanks for your help but still doesn't show anything.

Comment: @EmreOztoprak, Have you set the display member and value member properties

Comment: if you mean DataTextField and DatavalueField, yeah I set it. https://ibb.co/DbvNnyX

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Create a class which contains two properties named `Werks` and `NAME1`.

```
public class DemoModel
{
    public string Werks { get; set; }
    public string NAME1 { get; set; }
}
```

Receive the JSON result in the model like

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DemoModel>(response);
foreach (var item in result)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(item.NAME1);
}
```

I hope it will help you.

**Updated Answer**. 
Use can use DropDownList1.Items.Add or DataSource. If you are binding using DataSource you need to set DisplayMember and value member properties.

Here is an example

```
class ProductPalces
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Werk { get; set; }
}
```

Add some values to model
            List WerkList = new List();

```
        ProductPalces test1 = new ProductPalces() {
            Name = "name1",
            Werk = "Werk1"
        };

        ProductPalces test2 = new ProductPalces()
        {
            Name = "name2",
            Werk = "Werk2"
        };

        WerkList.Add(test1);
        WerkList.Add(test2);

        comboBox1.DataSource = WerkList;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Werk";
```

Comment: Guys,I got name1 from web api result but doesn't show to the dropdownlist menu. you can see the image https://ibb.co/zJ9WwcK.. Thanks for your help

Comment: @EmreOztoprak, I am not sure why you are using DataSource and DataBind. DropDownList1.Items.Add will add the values to the dropdown

Comment: @EmreOztoprak, I have updated the answer. Please check it